# Wave-Function Normalization in Momentum Space Not Possible

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, wavefunction, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

[image]

Hello,

I just have a question about this passage; specifically, I do not understand why the result of the inner product (the integral of u_k* and u_k') being the delta function defies conventional normalization. I was under the impression that this is the expected result, due to the orthogonality of eigenfunctions. If you could explain a little bit about normalization of the momentum wave function, I would really appreciate it. I have also attached a link of the full text below:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-02-introduction-to-applied-nuclear-physics-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT22_02S12_lec_ch2.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: I think you might be confusing the Kronecker delta with the Dirac delta.

Answer (score 2):

For a set of orthogonal wavefunctions, the usual normalization condition is the *Kronecker* delta:

$$\int u_k u_{k'}^* = \delta_{kk'}$$

which is $1$ when $k=k'$ and zero otherwise.

Here we have the *Dirac* delta, which is *infinite* when $k=k'$ and zero otherwise. Conceptually this is because the momentum eigenfunctions (plane waves) do not fall off at infinity, so they have infinite area.